# why the condition_variable waits indefinitely

Tags: c++11, condition-variable

Consider the following code snippet

```
#include <future>

std::mutex asyncMut_;
std::atomic<bool> isAsyncOperAllowed = false;
std::condition_variable cv;

void asyncFunc()
{
    while (isAsyncOperAllowed)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(asyncMut_);
        cv.wait(ul, []()
        {
            return isAsyncOperAllowed == false;
        });
    }
}

int main()
{
    isAsyncOperAllowed = true;
    auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFunc);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(asyncMut_);
    isAsyncOperAllowed = false;
    cv.notify_one();

    fut.get();
}
```

I am expecting that once I change the status of the isAsyncOperAllowed variable and notify the condition variable, the condition variable inside the asyncFunc should exit the wait and asyncFync should return and the main should end.

I am observing that the condition variable keeps waiting indefinitely. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am on Win10 - VS2015

Comment: Also in C++ you don't need to wrap the ` cv.wait(ul, []() {...})` inside a loop to handle spurious wakes.  The  library performs the loop over the predicate for you. If you used the overload of `wait()` that doesn't take a predicate, you would need the `while` loop, just like if you were using the C API pthreads interface for condition variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deadlock: `main()` never unlocks `lg` so even though the `cv` in `asyncFunc()` gets notified it never gets an opportunity to run since it can't claim the lock.

Try:

```
int main()
{
    isAsyncOperAllowed = true;
    auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, asyncFunc);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(asyncMut_);
        isAsyncOperAllowed = false;
    }
    cv.notify_one();

    fut.get();
}
```